# No confirmation e-mail after Paypal payment

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to integrate Paypal payments on website and I got this form:

```
            <form method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" id="paypal_form">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd"             value="_xclick" />
                <input type="hidden" name="business"        value="mail@mail.com" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name"       value="Test payment" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number"     value="777" />
                <input type="hidden" name="amount"          value="1.99" />
                <input type="hidden" name="return"          value="http://myhost.com//successpaypal.php" />
                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return"   value="http://myhost.com/cancelpaypal.php" />
                <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping"     value="0" />
                <input type="hidden" name="rm"              value="2" />
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
                <input type="submit" value="Go to PayPal" />
            </form>
```

And payments goes fine until users needs to confirm payment. There is no e-mail sending. I was trying in the sandbox with couple e-mail from couple computers and a couple of days. Is there any way to remove confirmation of payment by e-mail or what can be wrong with my that form?

Comment: Are you saying you need to end an email or Paypal needs to send an email?

Comment: Yes. But I got no e-mail

Answer (score 9):

The sandbox environment doesn't send emails externally. Since anyone can open (and confirm) any email address on any account in sandbox, it would be total chaos.

Instead, you can find all relevant messages that otherwise would've been sent as emails under 'Dashboard' > 'Sandbox notifications' on https://developer.paypal.com/